# nancyfx posting json - Nancy.DynamicDictionary is empty

Tags: asp.net, nancy

I'm just starting to play with NancyFx to compare it with the .net MVC WebAPI stuff and I've hit an issue straight away.  As I understand it Nancy should handle serialization straight out of the box.  But I can't seem to get it working.

I have a Nancy Module that looks like this:

```
public class HelloWorld : NancyModule
{
    public HelloWorld()
    {
        Post["/"] = parameters =>
            {
                var myFieldValue = parameters.myField;
                return HttpStatusCode.OK;
            };
    }
}
```

And I post to it using Fiddler like this:

```
Headers:
    User-Agent: Fiddler
    Content-Type: application/json
    Host: localhost:3141
    Content-Length: 24
Request-Body: 
    {"myField" : "profit"}
```

However when the parameters object is empty (and so, therefore is the myFieldValue object).
I'm sure I've missed something really obvious, but I don't know what!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parameters are for captures in the url (e.g. /foo/{bar} would capture a bar variable in parameters. If you are posting JSON you should use the model binder (var foo =this.Bind();

I would recommend taking a look at the docs too.. All of this is covered there :-)

Answer (score 4):

For posting data you have to use [model binding](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding).
Unfortunately, model binding to dynamic is not supported and you have to create request classes. There is a proposed [workaround](https://gist.github.com/thecodejunkie/5521941) , but I didn't use it myself.

If you don't want to define class for particular request and use model binding, then you can use power of `dynamic` with json.net.
Example:

```
public AuthTokenModule (IAuthService authService, UserMapper mapper) : base ("api/v1/authToken")
    {
        Post ["/login"] = x => {
            dynamic request = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (Request.Body.AsString ());

            var user = mapper.ValidateUser ((string)request.email, (string)request.password);
```