# Nancy (C#): How do I get my post data?

Tags: c#, lua, coronasdk, nancy

I'm using Corona SDK to post data to my C# server:

```
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
headers["Accept-Language"] = "en-US"

local body = "color=red&size=small"

local params = {}
params.headers = headers
params.body = body

network.request( host .. "/UpdateHand", "POST", nwListener, params )
```

I receive a message on the server:

```
  Post["/UpdateHand"] = x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received ...");
            return "Ok";
        };
```

But when I check the data (when I put a breakpoint on it) I don't see where my data is locaded (i.e. the params.body or params.headers). How can I extract this information?

I should POST it correctly according to the documentation on Corona: http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/library/network/request.html

Comment: If you don't want to use model binding, check out this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30571313/790465

Comment: Corona____ :) Getting popular.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The post data is in

```
this.Request.Body
```

If you have suitable type you can deserialize your data to it using model binding:

```
var x = this.Bind<YourType>();
```

Comment: Thanks, I do not have a suitable type for the moment so I did the first one. My output is, when I do var b = this.Request.Body, is "Nancy.IO.RequestStream". Shouldn't that receive the body as it is being sent?

Comment: Ok, so this seems to give some of the desired output: var id = this.Request.Body;
                byte[] data = new byte[10];
                id.Read(data, 0, 5);
                Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data));

Comment: If memory serves there is a AsString extension method for RequestStream, so you can get the body as a string by doing this.Request.Body.AsString()

Comment: @ChristianHorsdal that's in the Nancy.Extensions namespace

Answer (score 18):

There is a Nancy extension for this.  You will need to include the namespace for it.

```
using Nancy.Extensions;
var text =  Context.Request.Body.AsString();
```

I like how concise this is, part of Nancy's super-duper easy path.

But a word of caution!  This method leaves the stream at the end, so subsequent calls will return empty string.  To fix this, always reset the stream immediately afterwards, like so:

```
Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Nancy 2.0 is supposed to correct this so that the stream position is reset by default.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/2158

Comment: Using Nancy 2.0.0 - but `Context.Request.Body` is a `System.IO.Stream` - so no `AsString` available :(

Comment: Ian - it should be in Nancy.Extensions.

Answer (score 8):

This actually works great:

```
var body = this.Request.Body; 
int length = (int) body.Length; // this is a dynamic variable
byte[] data = new byte[length]; 
body.Read(data, 0, length);             
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(data));
```

Answer (score 3):

For Nancy 2.0.0, `Request.Body` is a `Stream` rather than a `RequestStream`, so doesn't have an `AsString` method.  However, this seems to work:

```
using (var reqStream = RequestStream.FromStream(Request.Body))
{
    var body = reqStream.AsString();
    // ... do stuff with body
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally getting your post data could be accomplished with a simple Bind() call. However, I've seen inconsistent results when using a Bind in a post call such that I've resorted to using the scheme outlined above.

I've seen various discussions about Nancy Bind() working and not working... I've seen both with Post but cannot explain the inconsistency. Where I saw it function properly was where I could guarantee the body of the request was managed as follows:

```
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream ()) {
            stream.Write (data, 0, data.Length);
        }
```

However, when sending data that should have been similarly handled (though I couldn't confirm) through WSO2 infrastructure (data serialized as a JSON event dictionary sent to a service proxy), Bind failed while the method above succeeded.